# Window Form Control Library that use WebBrowser generate property pane in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017, user-controls

I create a Window Form Control Library and in user control designer I add a web browser component. In control load I add this code:

```
 private void MyWebBrowserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
 }
```

I add just this user control to tool box of another windows form project but it generate property pane an select user control combo box for the for. I do not know where they came from. 
[image]

and:

[image]

How to remove every thing except `MyWebBrowser` in windows form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is a user control library project. You are running that project in debug mode. As a user control library project cannot actually run as an application it opens the screen you see. This allows you to test the user controls in your project. You select your user controls from the drop down and can change properties from the property grid.

If you look at your solution explorer you will see that your user control project is listed in **Bold** text:

[image: Projects]

This means that the control library is the default project that will run when you press the debug button.

To change this, right click on your windows forms application project and select `Set as StartUp Project` from the list.

[image: Set as start up project]

Your windows forms project will now be shown in **Bold** text:

[image: Changed start up]

Now, when you start debugging the solution it will run the Windows Forms Application instead of the User Control Library.